# Does $A \subset \cup_{i=1}^{\infty}U_i$ and $B \subset \cup_{n=1}^{\infty}V_n$ imply $A \times B \subset \cup_{i,n}(U_i \times V_n)$?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

If $A \subset \cup_{i=1}^{\infty}U_i$ and $B \subset \cup_{n=1}^{\infty}V_n$, how can I show that $A \times B \subset \cup_{i,n}(U_i \times V_n)$?

Also, what would it mean for $A \times B \subset \cup_{i,n}(U_i \times V_n)$? I am a bit confused if $\cup_{i,n}(U_i \times V_n)$ is a double or single union. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Some hint*: Let $a\in U_i$ and $b\in V_n$ for some $i$, $n$, then $(a,b)\in U_i\times V_n$.

$\bigcup_{i,n}U_i\times V_n$ is equal to $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty U_i\times V_n$ (if you consider as double union.) or it is equal to $\bigcup_{(i,n)\in\Bbb{N}\times\Bbb{N}}U_i\times V_n$ (if you consider it as single union.)

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively the answer is yes.

What you need to do is prove that $E \times (\cup^{\infty}_k F_k)$ is what you think it is.

Then the proof is immediate as also the fact that $A \subset B, C \subset D \implies A \times B \subset C \times D$ which you almost don't even need a proof for.

With some homework, *QED*

Comment: Just a small typo in the last implication, should be $A\times C$ in $B\times D$.